# Is it possible to have a gtk window of a random size with a grid inside it

Tags: c, window, gtk

I have a c gtk window with a grid inside it, it all works but I wanted to make the window bigger but it's not currently allowing me too

Answer (score 1):

Just generate two random numbers and use those numbers as the size dimensions when you define your window. I'm really a little confused about what you are asking.

Comment: Although it seems impossible to answer this, you did it.